# Changing icons order of VSCode status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to change my VSCode status bar's icons order but I don't know how to do it.
I saw only one solution but it was outdated and it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link to that outdated information?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Short of creating your own VS Code extension, there isn't a easy solution to this problem yet. This is, however, a work-in-progress feature which you can track [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35744).

I hope this helps :)